# How to unit test constructor when using nested test classes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net

Assuming I have some logic in a class constructor that I wish to unit test, how would I structure it if I am using **xUnit.net** and nested test classes for each method?

```
using Xunit;

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        // Some logic to test
    }

    public int GetResult()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}

public class MyClassFacts
{
    // How to test MyClass constructor?

    // Nested classes to test each of MyClass' methods
    public class GetResult
    {
        [Fact]
        public void IsCorrect()
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            int result = myClass.GetResult();
            Assert.Equal(123, result);
        }

        // Other tests for MyClass.GetResult()...
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need a failing test

Comment: @quamrana I'm not sure what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already testing it in your IsCorrect() test technically but if you want an explicit test:

```
using Xunit;

public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        // Some logic to test
    }

    public int GetResult()
    {
        return 123;
    }
}

public class MyClassFacts
{
    [Fact]
    public void Ctor()
    {
        var myClass = new MyClass();
        Assert.NotNull(myClass);
        // Any other asserts you require
    }

    // Nested classes to test each of MyClass' methods
    public class GetResult
    {
        [Fact]
        public void IsCorrect()
        {
            var myClass = new MyClass();
            int result = myClass.GetResult();
            Assert.Equal(123, result);
        }

        // Other tests for MyClass.GetResult()...
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the constructor tests should go in a nested class, just like the other methods (see `MyClass.GetResult`)? For example: `public class Ctor {[Fact] public void CtorTest(){}}`

Comment: It's really up to you but based on the structure you have currently I would say yes. This would make it consistent. If you're looking at a good way to structure your tests, have a read of http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/02/structuring-unit-tests.aspx/ which has some good suggestions, as do some of the comments.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the article that got me interested in structuring my tests this way in the first place :D

Comment: You can read this article for a different point of view also - http://ayende.com/blog/152897/structuring-your-unit-tests-why

Comment: Not an article I would have expected Ayende to write! Interesting that most of the people in the comments seem to be disagreeing and actually following the advice of Phil Haack...

Comment: Ayende loves a bit of contraversy :)